# Физический размер экрана

Tags: winapi, c#

Подскажите, возможно ли средствами С# или WinApi получить информацию о физических размерах экрана: диагональ или ширину и высоту?

Comment: Отпишитесь пожалуйста у кого совпали результаты с линейкой Ж-) У меня врёт безбожно.

Answer (score 2):

Используя только .NET нет возможности получить физические размеры. В Windows API есть функция GetDeviceCaps, вызываемая с параметрами HORZSIZE и VERTSIZE, она может дать требуемые значения.

Answer (score 0):

Используя .Net
System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize;

Answer (score -1):

На C# не знаю,а на Visual Basic 6 можно так:

Private Sub cmdScreen_Click()
Print Screen.Height / 15 & " высота"
Print Screen.Width / 15 & " ширина"
End Sub

Answer (score -1):

```
using (Graphics g = CreateGraphics())
{
  int W = (int)(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / g.DpiX * 2.54)
  int H = (int)(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height / g.DpiY * 2.54)
}
```

вроде так работает